# check url param from set

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a set of words, and I want that the component will read the value from the url (like  `localhost:4200/classify/bbc` ) and if the value is in the set, the relevant radio will be selected.
If value is not in the set a comment will appear to the user.

classify.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'classify',
  templateUrl: './classify.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./classify.component.css']
})
export class ClassifyComponent implements OnInit {
  favoriteChannel: string;
  channels: string[] = ['BBC', 'CNN', 'NBC'];

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.favoriteChannel = this.route.snapshot.params.channels;
  }

}
```

classify.component.html :

```
<label id="example-radio-group-label">Pick your favorite channel</label>
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
  class="example-radio-group"
  [(ngModel)]="favoriteChannel">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let channel of channels" [value]="channel">
    {{channel}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div>Your favorite channel is: {{favoriteChannel}}</div>
```

routing :

```
  { path: 'classify/:channels', component: ClassifyComponent },
```

nav.component.html :

```
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/classify','bbc']" routerLinkActive="active">Classify</a>
```

Comment: `channel` in your routing path but `channels` in `params.channels`

Comment: @Frank changed it, thank you. But can you help me with my question?

Comment: Try this: `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('channels');`

Comment: @Frank Didn't work.. I read that maybe I need a function in my ts file or with NgIf in the html, any idea?

Comment: The code seems OK, try subscribe to paramMap see if it gets the parameters: `    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      console.log(params.keys);
      console.log(params.get('channels'));
    });`